# How to use text/html in a BPMN documentation/textAnnotation element

Tags: eclipse, jbpm, bpmn, ibm-bpm

I am trying to create a custom format based on the BPMN 2.0 Interchange Format and I am wondering what BPMN tools are doing to support the textFormat attribute of the documentation and textAnnotation elements.

For example, I created a simple sample as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
  id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="sample">
  <process id="bpmn_65f0e673_475e_4776_a685_42be7e93cc8f" name="simple-1"
    isExecutable="false" processType="Private">
    <startEvent id="start" name="Start">
      <outgoing>criteria</outgoing>
    </startEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="criteria" sourceRef="start" targetRef="treatment">
      <documentation id="doc_criteria" textFormat="text/html">
        <p>simple finding</p>
      </documentation>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <task id="treatment">
      <documentation id="doc_treatment" textFormat="text/html">
        <p>simple treatment</p>
      </documentation>
      <incoming>criteria</incoming>
      <outgoing>toEnd</outgoing>
    </task>
    <sequenceFlow id="toEnd" sourceRef="treatment" targetRef="end" />
    <endEvent id="end" name="End">
      <incoming>toEnd</incoming>
    </endEvent>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to load this into the Eclipse BPMN tooling, it generates the following error:

```
FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'p' not found. (platform:/resource/BPMN/model/simpler.bpmn, 11, 12)
```

Are there any examples of how text/html content should get encoded into BPMN?
Is it supported by any of the BPMN tooling?

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it by myself, but you can give it a try:

use a CDATA marker for your html text

[What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)